# GWT i18n Message Properties does not Display special Character like ß

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, internationalization

I use GWT i18n [Messages](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Messages.html) to translate messages:

```
@DefaultLocale("en")
public interface Messages extends com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Messages {

    @DefaultMessage("Size")
    String size();

}
```

For German I have the `Messages_de.properties` file.

```
size=Größe äüö ÄÖÜ
```

In one of my UIBinder templates I use

```
<ui:text with="{messages.size}"/>
```

When the user's browser is `de`I get `Grösse ÄÖÜ ÄÖÜ`instead of `Größe äüö ÄÖÜ`being displayed.

My workspace as well as my .properties file is set to UTF8.

**How can I get the special character `ß` in German being displayed correctly or is there a way to include ASCII code?**

Solution: When you set CSS `text-transform: uppercase;` then `ß` is transformed to `SS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with the way Eclipse handles `properties` files. You can set the whole workspace to UTF-8, it will still treat `properties` files as `ISO 8859-1` - because [that's the default/expected encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). However, GWT uses [an enhanced properties file format](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html#DevGuidePropertiesFiles) that uses UTF-8 directly (without the need for escaping the characters).

You have to override this setting separately:

[image: Setting encoding for properties files in Eclipse]

You can change the default encoding for all `*.properties` files to `UTF-8` there (don't forget to hit the `Update` button).

**But please note that this will mean treating all `properties` files as UTF-8**. So unless you are sure this will not break anything, I'd narrow down the file association for example to `*Messages.properties` files (if all your translation files have the `Messages` suffix). Or just use a different editor for editing the properties files.

Answer (score 1):

GWT is always UTF8. So the easiest way to solve your problem is, to set the encoding of your workspace to utf-8.

Or select your Messages_de.properties, right mouse button and select properties. Use Resources to set the encoding of your property file to utf-8.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the encoding inside the browser?

Comment: All my files are UTF8

Comment: You can enter the special charakter as utf8-codes. this will work. But therre is another problem. Just checked with my projects. German chraceters like ä, ü, etc. are no problem.

Comment: German characters like ä, ü, ö are displayed as Ä, Ü, Ö they are always in capital letters.